# Find a matrix $A$ such that $X$ generates the subspace $W$ (the solution space of the system $AX=0$.)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Consider $W$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ generated by:
\begin{align*}
X=\left \{(1,-1,0,5,1), (1,0,1,0,-2),(-2,0,-1,0,-1)\right \}
\end{align*}
Find a system of linear equations $AX=0$ such that W be the solution space of the system.

I understand that what I've to do is to find a matrix $A_{5x5}$ such that:

\begin{align*}
A \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-1\\ 
0\\ 
5\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} \ \text{  ,  } \ A \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
-2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} \ \text{ and, } \ A \begin{pmatrix}
-2\\ 
0\\ 
-1\\ 
0\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}

So I think that the solution can be to propose a new system of linear equations but I'm not sure how can I do it. How can I find the matrix $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $W$ is $3$-dimensional, you need the $2$-dimensional orthogonal space, putting the generating vectors as rows of $A$.

$$0=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0&5&1\\1&0&1&0&-2\\-2&0&-1&0&-1\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&3\\0&1&0&-5&2\\0&0&1&0&-5\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{x}$$ so $\mathbf{x}=(-3t,5s-2t,5t,s,t)=t(-3,-2,5,0,1)+s(0,5,0,1,0)$.

Thus $$A=\begin{pmatrix}-3&-2&5&0&1\\0&5&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ is one possible matrix. (Any equivalent matrix will do.)

Comment: $A$ should be $5\times5$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Thanks. :)

Comment: @Chrystomath Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help! One question, how did you know that the orthogonal space is 2-dimensional?

Comment: @luisegf A space and its orthogonal space complement each other, so $3+2=5$. It's like in 3-D. A plane and a perpendicular line have dimensions $2+1=3$, equal to the whole space. Also, the solutions came out to be 2-D by themselves (i.e. two free variables $s,t$).

Comment: @Chrystomath Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**  The kernel is the orthogonal complement of the row space.  So $A$ needs row space equal to $W^\perp$.